# getOffice365ActivationsUserDetail Graph API returns UnknownTenantId

Tags: json, office365, microsoft-graph-api

I am trying to get the information about the users that have **Activated Office 365** using:

```
/beta/reports/getOffice365ActivationsUserDetail?$format=text/csv
```

I am getting an error:

```
{
  "code": "UnknownTenantId",
  "message": "We do not recognize this tenant ID {MyTenantID}. Please double-check the tenant ID and try again."
}
```

The `Read.Report.All` permission is already assigned, and I am able to get other information from O365 using the Graph API. 
Any suggestions how to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't be using the `/beta/` release as this report is available in `/v1.0/` and returns `test/csv` by default.

You also need to provide a valid `period` to the [getOffice365ActiveUserDetail](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/reportroot_getoffice365activeuserdetail) endpoint:

> Specifies the length of time over which the report is aggregated. The supported values for `{period_value}` are: `D7`, `D30`, `D90`, and `D180`. These values follow the format Dn where n represents the number of days over which the report is aggregated.

For example, to get details for users active in past 7 days you would request:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/reports/getOffice365ActiveUserDetail(period='D7')
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. 
I needed the Activations, not the Active users, but the directions that you provided solved my issue. 
In case if someone is facing a similar issue with "Activations" Reports, the names of the columns in the CSV output, for "Windows OS" and "Mac OS" from the beta version are changed to "Windows" and "Mac"